# CSS Four Colors Gradient Animation

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am trying to reproduce this gradient animation using css and html.

[CSS Gradient](https://youtu.be/kBIlV5mJZWs)

This is how I imagine it to work:

```css
.gradient__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  filter: blur(1rem);
}

.gradient__block--1 {
  background-color: #e7402c;
}

.gradient__block--2 {
  background-color: #43ba88;
}

.gradient__block--3 {
  background-color: #50ccf1;
}

.gradient__block--3 {
  background-color: #704fee;
}
```

```html
<section class="gradient__wrapper">
  <div class="gradient__block--1"> ______________<br /> </div>
  <div class="gradient__block--2"> ______________<br /></div>
  <div class="gradient__block--3"> ______________<br /></div>
  <div class="gradient__block--4"> ______________<br /></div>
</section>
```

How can I make the div shifts to recreate this animation?

Thank you

Comment: I would take a look at https://codepen.io/P1N2O/pen/pyBNzX and start from there, then you can ask a question with running code, your example doesn't show anything. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See https://redstapler.co/css-animated-gradient-background/ also

Comment: what you've tried so far ?